# Run single task upto n times in django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Suppose I have task called  lazy_post_task.

code somethings like this

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def lazy_post_task(self, post_url):
    self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={})
    .............
```

Now i want to run this task upto n times and n depends on user input and also i want to wait until previous task complete.
i mean, suppose user input=2 then i want to run task upto 2 times but one at a time.

Comment: You could pass a value to the task, then have a function that the task calls, while keeping count in order to only call it `x` times. Otherwise, look at celery beat for proper task scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You can raise [`self.retry()`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.retry) exception to retry task. To get count of retries use [`self.request.retries`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-request):

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def lazy_post_task(self, post_url, max_retries):
    self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={})
    if max_retries < self.request.retries:
        raise self.retry()
```

Note that you also need to pass user's `max_retries` as argument.